# mysql select: randomly select with another criteria if not met the max. number of rows

Tags: select, where-clause

I need to select from a table under certain criteria with a LIMIT of 20 Randomly. I used following for the same

```
SELECT *, rand() FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE '%text%' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 20
```

But Sometimes criteria wont meet and only less than 20 rows are selected . in such cases i needed to add another select statement in which there will be another criteria and not equal to previous Selection (i mean DISTINCT)
How can i achieve this with single query (something like conditional query).

mytable defines as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable`(
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`house` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`place` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`VinRav_ExamZ_id`) );
```

content of table

```
id------name-------house------place--
1-------data1------data2------data3--
2-------data4------data5------data6--
3-------data7------data8------data6--
4-------data9------data9------data10--
5-------data11-----data8------data12--
```

then first query

```
SELECT *, rand() FROM mytable WHERE palce LIKE 'data6' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 20
```

which will give 2 rows < 20.

```
2-------data4------data5------data6--
3-------data7------data8------data6--
```

**in that case execute**

```
SELECT *, rand() FROM mytable WHERE house LIKE 'data8' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 20
```

which will return

```
3-------data7------data8------data6--
5-------data11-----data8------data12--
```

then as a combined i need to get

```
2-------data4------data5------data6--
3-------data7------data8------data6--
5-------data11-----data8------data12--
```

Thankz in advance

Comment: please show us your structure of table, and give some explanation, what kind of data do you store in your table?

Comment: You can chain `order by` like `ORDER BY column1, rand()`. It will then order by column1 first and inside this block randomly. If this block has less than 20 entries, the next block (for the next value of column1) will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
-- WHERE column1 LIKE '%text%'  -- (notice removed where)
ORDER BY 
    case when  column1 like '%text%'           then 1 
         when  column1 like '%secondCriteria%' then 2
         when  column1 like '%thirdCriteria%'  then 3
         else 4
    end, 
    rand() 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: sorry to be sooo dumb... i didn't get it now tooo....can u explain 1,2,3,4 in your code....do i need to replace them with select statements

Comment: no, the only thing that you need to replace are the searched '%texts%'.  Numbers 1,2,3,4 are "the priority" of selected records. if you remove "limit 20" you will have all records from the table. if you keep "limit 20" (as your question says), you will have 20 records that meat first condition. if there are less than 20, then 20 will be completed with second criteria, if still 20 are not suplied, records from third criteria are suplied, finaly if with the three criterias you can not fill 20 records, any record is given from the table. in each criteria, all are selected randomly

Comment: just try it with your real table with real strings